# Search Multiple Tables at in one query (MySQL/PHP#)

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I have about 15 tables, each table containing about 10, 000 rows and about 30 columns. I want the users of my site to be able to search for a Part Number, or a product/description and display the results. Regardless of which table it's in.

Each product page is the same as the name of each corresponding table. So if a product is found, it will just display a link to the correct page (the filename is the name of the table).

Can't we just do something like:

query = "find $q in dbase.tables"; ?

And if $q exists in a table, return the name of the table it was found in?

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the tables have the same structure you might be able to do that. (That sounds like it's a simplistic manual partitioning scheme.)

Anway to join multiple tables you can use

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl2
...
```

And to get your simple access method you might create a view on that concatenation:

```
CREATE VIEW alltables AS
    SELECT * ... UNION ...
```

Not ever tested this. But this view would then facilitate `SELECT * FROM alltables WHERE find($q)...` - you'd still need a valid query for the columns of course.

Comment: @Lucifer: Oooops, cool. I did not expect this to work that easily :]

Comment: It didn't lol. But As soon as I saw it I remembered reading about views with mysql ages ago in a book i bought, and i put the rest together wwith another query i already had :)

Answer (score 0):

why do u have so many tables? why not have only one table of part #'s, than another table of descriptions and join on the part number?

Comment: If I did it that way, there would be hundreds of tables.

Comment: do you know what a table is?   

how is your database organized?

Comment: The structure of the product system is too complex to have the tables the way you suggested.

Comment: thats is the normalized database structure. many tables all with basically the same information to be joined when needed

Comment: We've achieved way better performance by having this structure, instead of joining everything we needed. This way, queries stay simple, much faster loading/response times and easier for our customer to maintain.